# Struts 2 OGNL - Comparing two string values in validation.xml

Tags: java, struts2, validation, ognl

I am new to Struts2 and OGNL and am making a simple web application with a registration page. There are two fields, `password` and `repassword` (to re-enter the password) and using the validation framework i would like to validate that the two passwords match (I know that I can do it easily with JavaScript). Here is what I've got so far. All of the field-validators are working fine. This is my first non-field validator and I just cant get it to work.

```
<validator type="expression">
    <param name="expression">${password}!=${repassword}</param>
    <message>Passwords must match.</message>
</validator>
```

I tried both with

```
${password}!=${repassword}
```

and without

```
password!=repassword
```

the OGNL tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`expression`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/expression-validator.html) validator is a Non-Field Level validator. Use [`fieldexpression`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/fieldexpression-validator.html) validator which is a Field Level validator and validates using OGNL expression. And it must be equals (`==`) check.

```
<field name="password">
  <field-validator type="fieldexpression">
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[password == repassword]]></param>
    <message>Passwords must match.</message>
  </field-validator>
</field>
```

The [`expression`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/expression-validator.html) validator adds action errors. The [`fieldexpression`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/fieldexpression-validator.html) validator adds field errors.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I would still like to understand how to make it work as an expression validator. The two links above seem to be describing the same functionality just in different words.

Comment: @BLam85: Updated my answer a little bit. You can use expression validator but to view errors in JSP you need to use `<s:actionerror/>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
%{password == repassword}
```

The validator checks to boolean OGNL expression that both are equal.

Comment: That did not work... as expected. The validator failed whether or not the passwords matched. (i.e. The action returned input)  However the message was never displayed and i see the following warning in the console `Mar 1, 2013 12:59:28 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: Got result of null when trying to get Boolean.`

Comment: This OGNL expression evaluates to true if the values match.